# why pygame mixer works when i just type ' r ' in the load attribute?

Tags: python

i searched pygame documentation but i could not find anything related with that. I just read on stackoverflow, some guy type r before the link and it works!? Why this happens ?

```
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('C:\\Users\HP Envy\PycharmProjects\tictactoegame\tictactoesong.wav')
mixer.music.play()
#error is pygame.error: Couldn't open 'C:\Users\HP Envy\PycharmProjects ictactoegame    ictactoesong.wav' (it maybe does not see 't' letter)
# when it is
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load(r'C:\\Users\HP Envy\PycharmProjects\tictactoegame\tictactoesong.wav')
mixer.music.play()
#it works
```

Comment: Read about [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An r-string is a raw string. It means all backslashes are backslash characters. 
For example:

```py
print('foo\\')
print('bar\\')
```

would print

```
foo\
bar\
```

With an r-string:

```py
print(r'foo\\')
print(r'bar\\')
```

would print

```
foo\\
bar\\
```

Normally, the backslash character ('') is treated as the beginning of an escape code, like '\n', '\r', '\c', '\', etc.
A raw string treats backslashes as string literals, as in just normal characters. Printing `r'\n'` will literally print `\n`.